# diagnostic messages window is disabled.

Tags: simulink

I'm using Simulink of MATLAB R2017a. the diagnostic messages window is disabled. so when there is an error in simulation, MATLAB gives no error(diagnostic messages window is not showing) and stops running the simulation. because of this I can not find the problem in my Simulink file. this problem happened since few day ago and I didn't have this problem in the beginning.
How can I fix this problem to show diagnostic messages window? seems its a bug in this version. because I didn't have this problem in other versions.

Comment: Try to change the directory of Matlab workspace to any other folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because of firewall. when matlab blocks with fiere wall this hp